# Dibujar rutas en Google Maps desde Android, teniendo las lat/lng por donde debe ir la polyline

Tags: android, google-maps

Necesito dibujar rutas en Google Map desde Android, teniendo la latitud y la longitud (lat/lng) por donde debe ir la polyline. La app que hago captura la posición por donde va transitando una persona con su celular, y luego debe dibujarse esa ruta en el mapa. Lo que ocurre es que el GPS no es tan preciso, y al dibujar una polyline entre cada lat/lng que se captura, no queda una línea recta en las calles, sino que quedan jorobadas. No sé si hay alguna librería o algo que se pueda usar para que la ruta quede bien dibujada.

Comment: Buenas, tengo el mismo problema. Encontraste alguna soluccion?. Si es asi, seria de gran ayuda que compartas la respuesta al problema.

Answer (score 4):

[Acá](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/?hl=es) puedes ver como configurar tu proyecto para que soporte Google Maps obtener un API key y desde la documentación oficial de la clase [Polilyne](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline) y la creación de [formas](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes#polilineas), básicamente puedes ver como dibujar una `Polyline` de la siguiente manera. Recuerda que las `Polyline` deben ser modificadas desde el hilo principal o un `IllegalStateException` será lanzado en tiempo de ejecución:

```
 GoogleMap map;
 // ... get a map.
 // Add a thin red line from London to New York.
 Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
     .add(new LatLng(51.5, -0.1), new LatLng(40.7, -74.0))
     .width(5)
     .color(Color.RED));
```

Un [ejemplo completo](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/PolylineDemoActivity.java):

```
public class PolylineDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {...}

     @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        // Override the default content description on the view, for accessibility mode.
        // Ideally this string would be localised.
        map.setContentDescription("Google Map with polylines.");

        // A simple polyline with the default options from Melbourne-Adelaide-Perth.
        map.addPolyline((new PolylineOptions())
                .add(MELBOURNE, ADELAIDE, PERTH));

        // A geodesic polyline that goes around the world.
        mClickablePolyline = map.addPolyline((new PolylineOptions())
                .add(LHR, AKL, LAX, JFK, LHR)
                .width(5)
                .color(Color.BLUE)
                .geodesic(true)
                .clickable(mClickabilityCheckbox.isChecked()));

        // Rectangle centered at Sydney.  This polyline will be mutable.
        int radius = 5;
        PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions()
                .add(new LatLng(SYDNEY.latitude + radius, SYDNEY.longitude + radius))
                .add(new LatLng(SYDNEY.latitude + radius, SYDNEY.longitude - radius))
                .add(new LatLng(SYDNEY.latitude - radius, SYDNEY.longitude - radius))
                .add(new LatLng(SYDNEY.latitude - radius, SYDNEY.longitude + radius))
                .add(new LatLng(SYDNEY.latitude + radius, SYDNEY.longitude + radius));

        // Move the map so that it is centered on the mutable polyline.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(SYDNEY));
    }
```

**Nota:** Dejo links a la documentación oficial porque Google tiene mala (pero necesaria) costumbre de cambiarnos ciertos procedimientos de configuración de vez en cuando.

Espero ayude. saludos

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pasa no es solo dibujar la polyline, seria que dados unas lat/lng dibuje las polyline sobre el contorno de las calles. No atravezando digamos edificios o parques, nose si me explico.

Comment: Asumo que las coordenadas las estas obteniendo desde el sensor gps del teléfono verdad?

Comment: La verdad que en ese caso Google maps no tiene métodos para ajustar lo que necesitas, por otra parte lo que puedes hacer es intentar optimizar el dispositivo que capturará las coordenadas para que lo haga lo más preciso posible.

Comment: Si lo capturo desde el gps del cel. Si lo mas que he podido encontrar es el servicio de direcciones de google que te da las posibles rutas para ir de un lugar a otro, pero seria demasiado cada 50 o 100 mtrs de distancia consultar para que dibuje esa ruta ademas que no queda como una sola ruta

Comment: he trabajado con equipos GPS cellocator, enfora, syrus y ni un esos equipos especialmente diseñados para entregar posición gps son 100% precisos, lo que mas vas a tener es una aproximación pero por ahora no tendrás un dibujo de la trayectoria exacto a como van las calles, a menos que desarrolles tus propios algoritmos de ajuste, pero te implica conocer las lat/lag de todas las calles.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+latitude_cur+","+longitude_cur+"&daddr="+latitude+","+longitude));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER );     
    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Tal vez esta pregunta te ayude a resolver el problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710744/how-to-draw-road-directions-between-two-geocodes-in-android-google-map-v2

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez puedas guardar los checkpoints en variables temporales, y hacer que muestre una polyline que haya sido calculada como ruta en coche entre ambos checkpoints. Así le obligas a la polyline a respetar el dibujo original de las calles, cosa que no ocurre en modo peatón ni en modo libre como te está ocurriendo a ti.
Suerte compañero